# invert section (checkbox) Shopify

Tags: image, layout, shopify

I'm a very beginner in Shopify, I've been trying for hours now to invert the image with text section layout using a checkbox, (true, false) . I found how to do the same thing using a select with options, but i've been asked by my internship supervisor to use a checkbox in the schema settings rather than a select dropdown menu, can anyone please help, any ideas?

Comment: adding some code on what you did will be nice.

Comment: Need to share the code also, that you tried until